# Bounding $\underset{x\in \mathcal{X}}{\sup}\Bigg( \int_{}\frac{|h_{1}(u,x)-h_{2}(u,x)|^p}{|u|^{ps}}\ du \Bigg)^\frac{1}{p}$ by L2 norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I want to bound the expression $D_{s,p}(h_{1},h_{2})$ by $\|f(u,x)\|_{2}$ from below but have been facing difficulties. How to bound the last expression?

\begin{align}
D_{s,p}(h_{1},h_{2}) & := \underset{x\in \mathcal{X}}{\sup}\Bigg( \int_{}\frac{|h_{1}(u,x)-h_{2}(u,x)|^p}{|u|^{ps}}\ du \Bigg)^\frac{1}{p}\\
& = \underset{x\in \mathcal{X}}{\sup}\Bigg( \int_{}f^p(u,x)|u|^{-ps}\ du \Bigg)^\frac{1}{p}\\
& = \underset{x_0\in \mathcal{X}}{\sup}\Bigg(\|f^p(u;x)(u)^{-ps}\|_1\Bigg)^\frac{1}{p}\\
& \geq \underset{x\in \mathcal{X}}{\sup}\Bigg(\|f^p(u,x)\|_\frac{1}{p}\||u|^{-ps}\|_\frac{-1}{p-1}\Bigg)^\frac{1}{p} \qquad \qquad\left(\|fg\|_1\geq\| f\|_{\frac{1}{p}}\|g\|_{-\frac{1}{p-1}}\right)\\
& = \Bigg(\||u|^\frac{ps}{p-1}\|^\frac{-(p-1))}{p}_{1}\Bigg)\underset{x\in \mathcal{X}}{\sup}\|f(u,x)\|_{1}\\
& = \frac{\underset{x\in \mathcal{X}}{\sup}\|f(u,x)\|_{1}}{g(u;p)}\\
\end{align}

Comment: please add more details like what is $s$, is $p>1$?, where does $u$ belong to, I assume $u\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes, $p , s>1$ and $u\in \mathbb{R}$. And the $h$ function is bounded by 1.